# How to catch error in React fetch request

Tags: reactjs

I'm just learning React, so if my questions are a bit naive, sorry for that

Currently I'm creating a small React app, which fetch news via api and display them with some additional features

The problem I faced, is that I cannot catch error (error.status etc.) if my fetch failed

I tried to add .catch block and catch the error, but somehow it doesn't work for me,  the next question which comes - how to redirect to Error page in case of rejected promise, is it possible to do in fetch function directly?

Here is the fetch function:

```
 function getSearchResult() {     
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setSearchResult(data))
    }
```

If I got data, everything works fine, however, I cannot make any progress with error handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async await syntax

```
async function getSearchResult() {  
  let response;
  try {
     response = await fetch(apiUrl)
  } catch(error) {
     console.log('error')
  }

  if (response?.ok) {
    const data = await response.json()
    setSearchResult(data)
  } else {
    console.log(`error code: ${response?.status}`)
  }   
}
```

Async await is more clean but if you don't want the above syntax you can try this

```
function getSearchResult() {     
  fetch(apiUrl)
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status >= 200 && res.status <= 299) {
      return res.json()
    } else {
     // You can redirect to error page here or show an error toast
     throw Error('Error message');
    } 
   })
  .then(data => setSearchResult(data))
  .catch((error) => {
   console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! async/await syntax really works and  outputs error status to the console, even though it looks a bit  unusual to me. Will play with both options to decide which is better to use

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1:

You can add ***`.catch()`*** after the ***`.then()`***:

```js
function getSearchResult() {
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setSearchResult(data))
      .catch(error => {
          // Do something on error 
          console.log(error)
      })
}
```

#### Method 2:

Use ***`try`*** & ***`catch`*** instead.

```js
async function getSearchResult() {
    try {
        const request = await fetch(apiUrl)
        const data = await request.json()
        setSearchResult(data)
    }
    catch(error) {
        // Do something on error 
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly such syntax I originally used, and it seems the most logically clear and simple to me, however,  it does work only if request has succeeded.  Might be, it's not the problem of syntax used but because of api features

Comment: @Kseniya you can also use `try` & `catch` instead. I've updated my answer. And if it helps you then plesse mark it as the answer. So, others can be also benefited from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this `try catch` block please

```
try {

  let response = fetch(apiUrl);
  console.log(response .data);
}catch (error) {
  if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response)
  }
  else if (error.request)
      console.log(error.request);
  else
      console.log(error.message);
}
```